Dataframe with FROM and TO column. Unordered, Get correct combinations
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'from': ['Start', '21', '73', 'Start', '55', '1', '2', '3'],
    'to': ['21', '73', '55', '1', '54', '2', '3', '4']
})





from
to




0
Start
21


1
21
73


2
73
55


3
Start
1


4
55
54


5
1
2


6
2
3


7
3
4



desired output
[['Start', '21', '73', '55', '54'], ['Start', '1', '2', '3', '4']]

[EDIT]
So you begin with "Start" in the "from" column and find "21" in the "to" column of that row. You have to find "21" in the "from" column now and move on to "73". Then repeat the steps, until you can't find anything in "from", which indicates the connection is done.
The connections are acyclic and unbranched.
[END EDIT]
the rows don't have to be in the correct order, as for 55, 54.

This question needs clearer logic. There will be numerous cases of unordered and please attach logic on how it should be handled. It would be nice to provide another example as well.

Do you want a list of lists as output?

@mozway yes, a list of all connections in the dataframe. In the example there are only two

Got it, then you can consider it a graph problem and use networkx (see below)

@PandaKim what is unclear? you start from "Start", then get 21 in "to", then go back to column "from" find 21 and get the matching 73, etc. same thing for the other "Start"

@Paul you might want to break down your full example to demonstrate the logic (as I did in the above comment)

@mozway It also makes sense that it's clear, since it allows a common result.

This is a graph problem, you could use networkx to solve it.
First de-duplicate the Start, then create a directed graph, get the weakly_connected_components, then the dag_longest_path:
import networkx as nx

# deduplicate the Start
m = df['from'].eq('Start')
from_ = df['from'].mask(m, 'Start'+m.cumsum().astype(str))
# ['Start1', '21', '73', 'Start2', '55', '1', '2', '3']

# create a graph
G = nx.from_edgelist(zip(from_, df['to']),
                     create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# get isolated paths
out = [nx.dag_longest_path(G.subgraph(c))
       for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G)]

Output:
[['Start1', '21', '73', '55', '54'], ['Start2', '1', '2', '3', '4']]

Graph:

You could also use a python function to manually follow the path for each Start:
def find_path(df, frm='from', to='to'):
    # create a Series with from as index, to as values
    s = df.set_index(frm)[to]
    out = []
    # for each Start, follow the path
    for val in s[s.index=='Start']:
        out.append(['Start', val])
        while (val := s.get(val)) is not None:
            out[-1].append(val)
    return out

out = find_path(df)
# [['Start', '21', '73', '55', '54'], ['Start', '1', '2', '3', '4']]

NB. this is assuming the graphs are non cyclic, non branched. If this is the case you can detect the cycles by keeping a set of seen nodes. The branches can be handled as well, but more details on the expected logic are needed.

@ouroboros1 that's true, but I assumed an acyclic unbranched graph here (as shown in the example). It's possible to handle branched graphs with the first approach but this looks like a different question.

By "unordered" I assume OP meant that the output does not necessarily have the nodes in numeric order, but they should be ordered following the path.

You're right, this should be made explicit. @Paul could you confirm in the question that the graph is acyclic and unbranched?

Use BFS from networkX.
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'from': ['Start', '21', '73', 'Start', '55', '1', '2', '3'],
    'to': ['21', '73', '55', '1', '54', '2', '3', '4']
})

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(df[['from','to']].values)
print(G)#DiGraph with 9 nodes and 8 edges

start_nodes = df[df['from'] == 'Start']['to'].values
print(start_nodes)#['21' '1']

components = [list(nx.bfs_tree(G, source = sn).nodes ) for sn in  start_nodes]
print(components)
#[['21', '73', '55', '54'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]

